# What is the best method to develop Sencha Application and deploy it on Android and IOS?

Tags: android, cross-platform, sencha-touch-2.1

I have developed a Sencha Touch Application. My platform is Linux. I have done the following steps from developing to deploying it on Android:

1) Downloaded Sencha Touch and Sencha CMD.

2) After running the command

```
sencha generate app appname ../appname
```

My project was created. With the help of eclipse plugin I was able to open the project in Eclipse and make changes to it.

3) Built the project using

```
sencha app build production
```

4) Downloaded cordova for native packaging

5) Created a project in cordova using cordova create appname

6) Copied contents of sencha production to www folder of cordova application

7) Ran the following commands

```
  cordova prepare android
  cordova compile android
  cordova run android
```

After going through all these steps, I was able to run my application on my mobile.

But I have the following doubts.

1) Is this approach the best? Or is there any other way which is more efficient. Any tutorial or links will be of great help.

2) Is  Cordova really necessary in my case?  Because I am not using any of phone native features like camera, accerelometer etc. 
I tried using sencha native packaging for android. But when I run the following command,

`sencha app package build packager.json`,

it shows the following error.  `Sencha Native Package (stbuild) is currently unsupported on linux`
So, is there a way not to use cordova or phonegap and directly build using sencha native packaging.

3) How can I debug my application in Eclipse while deploying it on Android as I can debug my normal android application.

4) If I want to deploy it on ios, then is it possible to deploy it without using Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [instructions about using Sencha Touch with Cordova/Phonegap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova) from Sencha themselves. Make sure to download Sencha Cmd 4.0 or higher.

Their recommended way is to create a project with Sencha Cmd

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/SenchaTouch generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

initialize Cordova

```
sencha cordova init [AppID]
```

configure the config.xml at the root level of your project where your index.html file resides and build/run with

```
sencha app build -run native
```

This has worked great for me. Unfortunately you need a Mac in order to develop for iOS. Even with Sencha Touch and Cordova, Xcode is a requirement.

If you want your web app to be distributed through the app stores, to be natively installed on iPhones or Android devices then yes, you need some kind of wrapper around it. There are certainly other ways but Cordova/Phonegap is an easy starting point and since version 3.0 quite light weight in its core.